# How to round the mean number of people

Tags: average, rounding-error, rounding-unit

When you are calculating the average of the number of people who do something, and you get a value with decimal points, should I still round up when the decimal point is > or = 5, and round down when it's < 5?

e.g. if I get an average of 4.3, should I round up or down?

And if I get an average of 4.7, should I round up or down?

Answer (score 1):

There is no intrinsic reason to round at all.  Even though all your samples have a whole number of people the mean may well not.  Just report $4.3$ or $4.7$ or whatever you get.

If you are going to round it, the usual rounding rules apply, so $4.3$ would round to $4$ and $4.7$ would round to $5$ if you wanted a whole number.